# How can I get this powershell command to re-run itself

Tags: powershell

I would like this script to run continuously and be able to re-run the Get-Process function so that the output will update itself with new shells without the user having to manually provide input.

```
while($true){
    Clear-Host;
    Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -match "cmd|powershell|bash"} | Format-Table Name,Id,StartTime;;
    $badshell = Read-Host "What shell would you like to kill(Id)? Your shell=$PID";
    Stop-Process -Id "$badshell" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

Example output:

```
Name         Id StartTime
----         -- ---------
powershell 7228 4/14/2023 12:48:04 PM


What shell would you like to kill(Id)? Your shell=7228:
```

I have tried to use the Start-Sleep cmdlet to restart the script, but this will only occur if the users gives input. I would like it to run the Get-Process function every 10 seconds even if the user has given no input.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do this?

Comment: I am preparing for a blue team event and this script will help us lookout for new shells being created by the red team...

Comment: The easiest way to do this probably would be to have "process list" updated in one window and prompt for process id to happen in another. Windows Terminal supports splitting windows into [panes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/panes) that could make it more manageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From feedback in comments, it seems like the actual need is to have a `Read-Host` that does not block the thread until input is provided.

This would work but it wouldn't be a robust solution, the `Read-HostNoBlock` function would wait for user input for a specified amount of time and exit if timeout is reached or user input is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key but the problem it has is that if the user is in the middle of providing input and the timeout is reached then the input is lost.

If you want an infinite loop, you would use `while($true) {` instead.

```bash
function Read-HostWithTimeout {
    param(
        [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
        [int] $Timeout = 10
    )

    [timespan] $Timeout = [timespan]::FromSeconds($Timeout)
    $timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    $output = ''; $key = ''

    while($Timeout -gt $timer.Elapsed) {
        if([console]::KeyAvailable) {
            $key = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('IncludeKeyDown')
            # VirtualKeyCode `13` / `0x0D` is `Enter` Key
            # See "Virtual-Key Codes (Winuser.h) - Win32 apps"
            if($key.VirtualKeyCode -eq 13) {
                return $output
            }
            # append to the output only if the input Key matches
            # a word character, this is to avoid appending escape sequences
            # i.e.: Alt+Tab would be captured without this
            if($key.Character -match '\w') {
                $output += $key.Character
            }
        }
    }
}

$i = 1
while($i++ -le 10) {
    Clear-Host
    $proc = Get-Process cmd, powershell, bash, pwsh -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $proc | Format-Table Name, Id, StartTime

    Write-Host 'What shell would you like to kill(Id)?'
    $value = Read-HostWithTimeout

    if($value -in $proc.Id) {
        Stop-Process -Id $value
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does work to kill all shells as they appear(Scorched Earth Method), we are looking for something that allows you to choose what process ID you want to kill from the Get-Process cmdlt output

Comment: Hence the Read-Host cmdlt

Comment: @ChipsMcCoy so essentially, you're looking for `Read-Host` to not block your console forever ?

Comment: I updated the question with some output. I would like the name and Id pane to update every second with new output from the Get-Process cmdlt, so that if a new cmd or PowerShell console is executed the process ID will appear here. I am basically looking for a process monitoring tool.

Comment: So if I open a new command prompt this script will not show the process ID until I manually click enter to restart the while loop

Comment: If I got it right you may use 2 independend scripts/consoles - one running in a loop updating the list of shells. And one running in a loop asking wich one of the shells you want to end.

Comment: @ChipsMcCoy see my update. For future reference, please try to clarify this kind of things when asking. Your initial question was not clear in my opinion.