# Simpel Menu that choses and option after a timer runs out. My timer does not count down

Tags: powershell, timer, menu, progress-bar

I have this menu (example) that I am trying to work out. I tried multiple options and for some reason none of the timers run down.

```powershell
function Show-SimpleMenu {
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Simple Menu Options:"
Write-Host "1. Option 1"
Write-Host "2. Option 2"
Write-Host "3. Option 3"
Write-Host "Q. Quit"

    $timeout = 10
    $timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    
    while ($true) {
        $elapsedSeconds = [math]::Floor($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)
        $remainingSeconds = $timeout - $elapsedSeconds
    
        if ($remainingSeconds -le 0) {
            Write-Host "Timeout: Automatically selecting Option 1."
            Option1
            break
        }
    
        Write-Host "Time Remaining: $remainingSeconds seconds"
    
        $selection = Read-Host "Enter your selection"
    
        switch ($selection) {
            '1' {
                Option1
                break
            }
            '2' {
                Option2
                break
            }
            '3' {
                Option3
                break
            }
            'Q' {
                Write-Host "Exiting..."
                return
            }
            default {
                Write-Host "Invalid selection."
            }
        }
    }

}

function Option1 {
Write-Host "Option 1 selected"
}

function Option2 {
Write-Host "Option 2 selected"
}

function Option3 {
Write-Host "Option 3 selected"
}

# Call the menu function

Show-SimpleMenu
```

But even using Write-Progress and Start-Sleep don't work.
Running a timer seperate works just fine.

I have only worked with powershell for a couple months now.

I wanted to create a menu for a user to choose from.
And if they don't choose an option then it with select option1 after x amount of seconds.

I feel like I am mission something. Tried to run in from Powershell ISE and Windows Powershell 5

Comment: perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76017150/how-can-i-get-this-powershell-command-to-re-run-itself/76017288#76017288, `Read-Host` will block the thread awaiting for user input, its not built for what you're looking for

Comment: it might be just better to go for a UI with winforms rather than rebuilding `Read-Host` honestly

Comment: At a later date there wil be a switch to using forms but have to rebuild everything. As it stands the current script is in use. But at times the user starts it most of the time needsn start the first option in the menu. so to make it convenient I would like it have it start after a fews seconds. A bit like we had in the old days on the windows 98 boot discs :D

Comment: Also thank you, I was unware that read-host works this way. This is the biggest help. Cause I am basiclly trying to do something that doesnt work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you run the timer in a job instead and then have it send a keystroke to the active window, that should work.

```
function Show-Menu {
    Write-OutPut @'
    Press 1
    Press 2
'@

  $TimeOut = Start-Job {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms') > $null
    sleep -Seconds 10

    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{ENTER}')
    # [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('1{ENTER}') #For option 1
  }
    
  $choice = Read-Host 'Enter your selection'
  Remove-Job $TimeOut -Force

  if (!$choice) {
    Write-Output 'Selection timed out'
    return
  }

  $choice
}

Show-Menu
```

See [MS Learn - System.Windows.Forms - SendKeys Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) and [SpiceWorks - Script who interacts with a window](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2234139-script-who-interacts-with-a-window#entry-8575005) for more details about `SendWait`.